# inherit a Cython class in a Python class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, cython

I have two classes which are written in `cython` and I want to use them in a class in `python`.

**position.pyx**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
cpdef double std_G,v=4.3e-9, 299792.458 

cdef class cosmo(object):
    cdef public double o_m, o_l, h, w, o_r, G, v
    def __init__(self,double o_m = 0.3, double o_l = 0.7, double h = 0.7, double w = -1, double o_r = 0., double G = std_G):

        self.o_m = o_m
        self.o_l = o_l
        self.o_r = o_r
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.G = G
        self.v = v

    def __copy__(self):

        return cosmo(o_m = self.o_m, o_l = self.o_l, h = self.h, w = self.w, o_r = self.o_r, G = self.G)

    property H0:
        def __get__(self):
            return 100*self.h  

    property M_solar:
        def __get__(self):
            return 1.989e30 

    property Mpc_to_m:
        def __get__(self):
            return 3.0856e22; 

    def hubble2(self, double z):
        cdef double inv_a
        inv_a = 1.+z
        return (self.o_r*inv_a**4 + self.o_m*inv_a**3 + \
                  self.o_l*(inv_a**(3*(1+self.w))) + (1 - self.o_m - self.o_l - self.o_r)*inv_a**2)*self.H0**2

    property hubble_length:
        def __get__(self):
            return self.v / self.H0

    def rc(self, double z):

        return 3.*self.hubble2(z)/(8*np.pi*self.G)

cdef class PositionsD(object):

     cdef double [:] _x
     property x:
         def __get__(self):
             return np.array(self._x)
         def __set__(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_T, ndim=1] x):
             self._x = x

     cdef double [:] _y
     property y:
         def __get__(self):
             return np.array(self._y)
         def __set__(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_T, ndim=1, mode='c'] y):
             self._y = y

     def __init__(self, np.ndarray[DTYPE_T, ndim=2, mode='c'] positions):
         self._x = positions[:,0]
         self._y = positions[:,1]
```

While I want to use `PositionsD` class in `modelfit` class while `modelfit` would inherit the property of `PositionsD`:

```
from position import *
import numpy as np
class modelfit(PositionsD):
    cosmo = cosmo()
    def __init__(self):
        super(modelfit,self).__init__(shear_pos)

        self.arcsec2rad = 2*np.pi/180./3600.
        self.shear_g = None
        self.shear_pos = shear_pos *self.arcsec2rad
        self.shear_z = None
        self.halo_pos = None
        self.halo_z = None
        self.sigma_g = np.sqrt(np.std(self.shear_g[:,1]**2+self.shear_g[:,2]**2))/np.sqrt(2)
        self.n_model_evals = 0
        self.gaussian_prior_theta = [{'mean' : 14, 'std': 0.5}]
        self.rho_c= cosmo.rc(self.halo_z)
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
>>> x=np.array([[0.3,-0.1],[1,3.4]])
>>> mf=modelfit(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: Now what's `init`? Use `__init__`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary There was a mistake. I updated.

Comment: `modelfit`'s `__init__` currently expects no arguments and you're passing it one.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary If I don't pass any argument, I would get this error :`NameError: global name 'shear_pos' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out for my application the best way to use the property of `PositionsD` class is to use it as following:

```
from position import *
import numpy as np
class modelfit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cosmo = cosmo()
        self.arcsec2rad = 2*np.pi/180./3600.
        self.shear_g = None
        self.source_pos = None
        self.shear_z = None
        self.halo_pos = None
        self.halo_z = None
        self.gaussian_prior_theta = [{'mean' : 14, 'std': 0.5}]
    def get_shear_pos(self): 
        return PositionsD(self.source_pos*self.arcsec2rad)

    shear_pos = property(get_shear_pos)

    def get_halo_center(self): 
        return PositionsD(self.halo_pos*self.arcsec2rad)

    halo_center = property(get_halo_center)

    def get_sigma_g(self):
        return np.sqrt(np.std(self.shear_g[:,1]**2+self.shear_g[:,2]**2))/np.sqrt(2)

    sigma_g = property(get_sigma_g)
    def get_rho_c(self):
        return self.cosmo.rc(self.halo_z)

    rho_c = property(get_rho_c)
```

An example of the application I was looking for is given as:

```
>>> m=modelfit()
>>> r=np.array([[0.2,-0.5],[2.1,9.3],[3.1,-2.8],[0.01,0.211]])
>>> m.source_pos=r
>>> m.shear_pos
<position.PositionsD object at 0x7f91a40e81e0>
>>> m.shear_pos.x
array([  1.93925472e-06,   2.03621746e-05,   3.00584482e-05,
         9.69627362e-08])
>>> m.shear_pos.x/m.arcsec2rad
array([ 0.2 ,  2.1 ,  3.1 ,  0.01])
>>> m.shear_pos.y/m.arcsec2rad
array([-0.5  ,  9.3  , -2.8  ,  0.211])
```

Answer (score 2):

In your current class definition, `__init__` does not expect any argument. That is why an error is raised when you call `mf=modelfit(x)`. Since `shear_pos`would not be defined otherwise, I assume that you intend to pass it as an argument in your class initialization. If so, you should write:

```
class modelfit(PositionsD):
    cosmo = cosmo()
    def __init__(self, shear_pos):
        super(modelfit,self).__init__(shear_pos)
        ...
```